# How to change constants in AutoLayout constraints that are created in IB programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` that represents a player with a profile picture, two labels and other two other state-dependent `UIImageViews`.
[image]

I have set up the cell with AutoLayout constraints in Storyboards and it works pretty well. The only minor issue is that the width of the cell is sometimes  (depending on its state) a little bit too wide for the iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. I have set the horizontal spacings (leading and trailing spaces between the elements) rather generously, which makes it look nice on the larger iPhones 6 and 6 plus.

However, I would like to remove a few points in the constants of the constraints, when I am on an iPhone 4 or 5. Size classes don't help me here, since my app only works in Portrait, and all iPhones have the same size class here. **What I am looking for is an easy way to adjust the constants of the horizontal space constraints that I have set in storyboards within my code.**

Comment: You say "vertical" but then discuss leading and trailing constraints and width, which are horizontal. Also, you generally want auto layout to adjust automatically to minor changes in width or the like. That is, use constraints which are based on proportion of the superview width or the like. (For example, use spacer views, as ugly as that is, and constrain their width to be related to the superview width by a multiplier.)

Comment: thanks for the hint with the orientation, of course I meant horizontal. just updated this in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have assigned a variable similarly as you would for any UI element - NSLayoutConstraint.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelConstraint;
```

And in the code you would do something like:

```
self.labelConstraint.constant = 10;
```

Comment: But this may result in conflicting constraints

Comment: If the constant of a constraint could not possibly have a different value without causing a conflict, then that constraint is redundant. In any case, this is the correct answer to what you asked. If you have to modify multiple constraints, then disable/remove them, modify their constants, and re-enable/re-add them.